# How do I get nVidia drivers working on new 2012 iMac?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, mac, nouveau

I can't get nVidia drivers working on my new iMac. It has the GeForce GTX 680MX card and I believe it's currently using the nouveau drivers. Whenever I install the nVidia drivers (I've tried downloading the proprietary ones from their site, installing nvidia-current, and nvidia-current-updates), it boots to a black screen. I can still get to tty by CTR+ALT+F1, but no desktop. I also don't have Unity 3D working at the moment either... I've looked through all the forum posts I could find but none worked and all seemed to be slightly different than my predicament. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

output from /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p:

```
OpenGL vendor string:   VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x301)
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Mesa 9.0

Not software rendered:    no
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       no
```

output from lspci | grep VGA:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 11a3 (rev a1)
```

output from lsmod:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
joydev                 17694  0 
hid_magicmouse         17939  0 
hidp                   22516  1 
nouveau               924024  2 
ttm                    88495  1 nouveau
drm_kms_helper         49259  1 nouveau
drm                   290344  4 nouveau,ttm,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13565  1 nouveau
mxm_wmi                13022  1 nouveau
wmi                    19257  2 nouveau,mxm_wmi
vesafb                 13846  0 
btusb                  22432  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32476  1 
lib80211_crypt_tkip    17391  0 
coretemp               13642  0 
kvm_intel             137888  0 
kvm                   422160  1 kvm_intel
ghash_clmulni_intel    13221  0 
aesni_intel            51134  0 
cryptd                 20531  2 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
aes_x86_64             17256  1 aesni_intel
hid_generic            12541  0 
hid_apple              13376  0 
applesmc               19515  0 
input_polldev          13897  1 applesmc
snd_hda_codec_cirrus    24052  1 
microcode              23030  0 
lpc_ich                17145  0 
parport_pc             32867  0 
wl                   3074942  0 
rfcomm                 47562  12 
cfg80211              208382  1 wl
lib80211               14382  2 lib80211_crypt_tkip,wl
bnep                   18240  2 
bluetooth             211812  29 hidp,btusb,rfcomm,bnep
snd_seq_midi           13325  0 
snd_rawmidi            30750  1 snd_seq_midi
ppdev                  17114  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14900  1 snd_seq_midi
uvcvideo               78117  0 
videobuf2_core         33025  1 uvcvideo
videodev              125126  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
videobuf2_vmalloc      12861  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13405  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
usbhid                 47259  0 
hid                   100815  5 hid_magicmouse,hidp,hid_generic,hid_apple,usbhid
snd_seq                61931  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         14498  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
snd_hda_intel          34117  5 
snd_hda_codec         135141  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_cirrus,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              17765  1 snd_hda_codec
video                  19653  1 nouveau
snd_pcm                97523  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
mac_hid                13254  0 
snd_timer              29990  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
mei                    41410  0 
snd                    83674  20 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_cirrus,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_timer
apple_bl               13674  0 
soundcore              15092  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18573  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
lp                     17800  0 
parport                46563  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
sdhci_pci              18749  0 
sdhci                  33145  1 sdhci_pci
```

Answer (score 0):

Your OpneGL Vendor String reports it's running VMware's opengl implementation. Have you previously run this install through VMware (fusion?)?

I'm guessing that you need to uninstall the VMware guest tools and reinstall the nvidia-current package.

The vmware guest tools uninstall utility is:

```
sudo vmware-uninstall-tools.pl
```

(hopefully that utility is in the PATH!)